# Layouts are overlapping in nuxt.js

Tags: css, nuxt.js

I'm working on a Nuxt.JS app. I've created two layouts one for public view and the other one for Dashboard (admin panel). The issue I'm facing is that the layout's styling is overlapping each other.

I've tried to make Layout styling "scoped" but didn't work properly, it miss the styling for body tag (might be others also). How can I fix it?

Comment: We are not able to identify the issue based on your description.

Comment: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3877

Comment: I got the solution myself... The layouts are over lapping because Body tag has been styled in both layouts. And when I scoped the css in layout, the body tag styling was not found, because by adding scoped attribute css only applies to the tags that exists in the component.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.